# Running some code before redirecting to a static file

Tags: asp.net-core, static-files, asp.net-core-middleware

I'm developing an asp.net core application that contains Images folder under wwwroot directory. My code looks like this

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.Map("/Images", images =>
        {
            images.Map("/test.png", test =>
            {
                printHello(app);
            });
        });
    }

private void printHello(IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        app.Run(async (context) =>
        {
            await context.Response.WriteAsync("Hello World!!");
        });
    }
```

So my problem is whenever I run the application and call this URL (http://localhost:5000/Images/test.png) its showing the Image without even mapping the URL in Configuration method. 
I need my code to run the code below before showing the Image, what should I add.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. StaticFiles middleware stops further pipeline execution.

   You may try to use `OnPrepareResponse` handler to do something before response will be sent back to client:

   ```
   var staticFileOptions = new StaticFileOptions()
       {
           OnPrepareResponse = ctx =>
           {
               // request is available via ctx.Context.Request
               // response is available via ctx.Context.Response
           }

       };

   app.UseStaticFiles(staticFileOptions);
   ```

---

2. Middlewares are called in the order they registered. Register some middleware before StaticFiles middleware and not stop pipeline execution in it (don't use `.Run`)

   See, if you just replace the order (and note that you need to pass `printHello` as a delegate, not execute it, otherwise it will be executed during app start), like this:

   ```
   public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
   {
      app.Map("/Images", images =>
      {
          images.Map("/test.png", printHello);
      });

      app.UseStaticFiles();
   }
   ```

   only first middleware will still be executed as you are using `app.Run(async (context) =>` inside `printHello`.

---

3. `await context.Response.WriteAsync` could be used only in final middlewares in the pipeline, as this starts the response and so next middleware may fail with next exception:

   > System.InvalidOperationException: "Headers are read-only, response has already started."

Comment: even after using the way written in number 2 and removing the app.Run from printHello method, the code didn't enter the method and its giving me this page when calling the URL: _The Image "http://localhost:5000/Images/test.png" cannot be displayed because it contains errors._

Comment: @Batman I have updated number 2. Your last problem is that `printHello` should be passed as a second parameter to `.Map` method

Comment: Yh i did use the updated one but its not using the map and its not viewing the image