# Is there an equivalent to app.UseStaticFiles() that allows my code to modify files before response is sent?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm creating a site where I mostly want files to be served statically, but I need to modify the content of some of the files.  I'd like to use something like `app.UseStaticFiles()`, but as far as I can tell the static file provider doesn't allow you to hook into it and make modifications to the static content before the response is sent.  I basically want to say "if the file is foo, make this modification to the body.  If it's bar, make some other modification to the body."

Is there a provider similar to `UseStaticFiles` that will allow me to do this, or is there some other way I can do it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Running some code before redirecting to a static file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47196014/running-some-code-before-redirecting-to-a-static-file)

Comment: @phuzi Nope, the `OnPrepareResponse` only lets you modify headers and not the body of the response.

Comment: Then you'll have to write your own middleware that runs before the static files middleware allowing you to handle requests to the files you need to handle and allowing others to be handled by staticfiles. I don't think there's anything "off the shelf" that you could use as you will likely want some custom handling of those files.

Comment: If you carefully went through ASP.NET Core documentation, file providers have been there for long, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/file-providers?view=aspnetcore-7.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up implementing an `IFileProvider` to be provided (via DI) to the static files middleware, allowing me to modify selected files beforehand.  There's quite a bit of implementation, though.  What I call `ModifiableFileProvider` also needs its own directory content and file info classes to return stuff with:

```
using System.Collections;
using Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders;

internal class ModifiableDirectoryContents : IDirectoryContents {
    #region Private vars

    private readonly IDirectoryContents _physicalDirectoryContents;
    private readonly Func<IFileInfo, IFileInfo> _cbModifyFile;

    #endregion

    #region Constructors

    public ModifiableDirectoryContents(IDirectoryContents physicalDirectoryContents, Func<IFileInfo, IFileInfo> cbModifyFile) {
        _physicalDirectoryContents = physicalDirectoryContents;
        _cbModifyFile = cbModifyFile;
    }

    #endregion

    #region Private methods

    private IEnumerator<IFileInfo> getEnumeratorInternal() {
        foreach (var fileInfo in _physicalDirectoryContents) {
            yield return _cbModifyFile(fileInfo);
        }
    }

    #endregion

    public bool Exists => _physicalDirectoryContents.Exists;

    public IEnumerator<IFileInfo> GetEnumerator() {
        return getEnumeratorInternal();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() {
        return getEnumeratorInternal();
    }
}

internal class ModifiableFileInfo : IFileInfo {
    #region Private vars

    private readonly bool _exists;
    private readonly bool _isDirectory;
    private readonly DateTimeOffset _lastModified;
    private readonly long _length;
    private readonly string _name;
    private readonly string _physicalPath;
    private readonly Func<Stream> _readStreamFactory;

    #endregion

    #region Constructors

    public ModifiableFileInfo(bool exists, bool isDirectory, DateTimeOffset lastModified, long length, string name, string physicalPath, Func<Stream> readStreamFactory) {
        _exists = exists;
        _isDirectory = isDirectory;
        _lastModified = lastModified;
        _length = length;
        _name = name;
        _physicalPath = physicalPath;
        _readStreamFactory = readStreamFactory;
    }

    #endregion

    public bool Exists => _exists;

    public bool IsDirectory => _isDirectory;

    public DateTimeOffset LastModified => _lastModified;

    public long Length => _length;

    public string Name => _name;

    public string PhysicalPath => _physicalPath;

    public Stream CreateReadStream() {
        return _readStreamFactory();
    }
}
```

Once that's done, the `ModifiableFileProvider` can then be implemented:

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives;

public sealed class ModifiableFileProvider : IFileProvider, IDisposable {
    #region Private vars

    private readonly PhysicalFileProvider _fileProvider;
    private readonly Func<IFileInfo, bool> _cbShouldModifyFile;
    private readonly Func<string, byte[]> _cbModifyFile;
    private readonly bool _filePathBlankIfModified;

    #endregion

    #region Constructors

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of a modifiable file provider at the given root directory.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="root">The root directory. This should be an absolute path.</param>
    /// <param name="cbShouldModifyFile">
    /// A matcher callback that determines whether to modify the file.  Returns true to modify, false not to.
    /// Takes the IFileInfo for the file in question as returned from the internal PhysicalFileProvider, as
    /// an argument.
    /// </param>
    /// <param name="cbModifyFile">
    /// A function that modifies the file in the desired way, called if the matcher indicated that the file
    /// should be modified.  Takes the existing file contents as an argument, and returns the modified contents
    /// as bytes.
    /// </param>
    /// <param name="filePathBlankIfModified">
    /// Whether the physical file path should be set to blank (empty string) if the file is modified.  This is
    /// usually desirable, to force consuming code to get the modified file contents with CreateReadStream
    /// instead of getting it directly from the file system given the path.
    /// </param>
    public ModifiableFileProvider(string root, Func<IFileInfo, bool> cbShouldModifyFile, Func<string, byte[]> cbModifyFile, bool filePathBlankIfModified = true) {
        _fileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(root);
        _cbShouldModifyFile = cbShouldModifyFile;
        _cbModifyFile = cbModifyFile;
        _filePathBlankIfModified = filePathBlankIfModified;
    }

    #endregion

    #region Private methods

    private IFileInfo modifyFile(IFileInfo fileInfo) {
        if (!_cbShouldModifyFile(fileInfo)) {
            return fileInfo;
        }

        using var readStream = fileInfo.CreateReadStream();
        using var reader = new StreamReader(readStream);
        var contents = reader.ReadToEnd();
        var newContents = _cbModifyFile(contents);
        return new ModifiableFileInfo(
            fileInfo.Exists,
            fileInfo.IsDirectory,
            fileInfo.LastModified,
            newContents.Length,
            fileInfo.Name,
            _filePathBlankIfModified ? "" : fileInfo.PhysicalPath,
            () => {
                return new MemoryStream(newContents);
            }
        );
    }

    #endregion

    #region IFileProvider

    public IDirectoryContents GetDirectoryContents(string subpath) {
        var dirContents = _fileProvider.GetDirectoryContents(subpath);
        if (dirContents is NotFoundDirectoryContents) {
            // No chance of needing to modify anything with a 'not found'
            return dirContents;
        }

        return new ModifiableDirectoryContents(dirContents, modifyFile);
    }

    public IFileInfo GetFileInfo(string subpath) {
        return modifyFile(_fileProvider.GetFileInfo(subpath));
    }

    public IChangeToken Watch(string filter) {
        return _fileProvider.Watch(filter);
    }

    #endregion

    #region IDisposable

    public void Dispose() {
        _fileProvider.Dispose();
    }

    #endregion
}
```